# How to include data-rel, data-transition in Javascript to make entire row clickable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am replacing links so that entire rows of a table follow the path.

The link I am trying to replace:

```
<a href="#popupInfo" data-rel="popup" data-transition="slide" title="Learn more">
```

Current progress:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('table tr').click(function(){
        window.location = $(this).data('href');
        return false;
    });
});
```

and in the table...

```
<tr data-href="#popupInfo>
```

This works so far to go to #popupInfo, but I want to also include the data-ref, data-transition, etc. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: hmm.. any thoughts?